# How to analyse three way ANOVA that also has pre-post and one within subjects factor?

Tags: anova, spss

I'm currently having a problem understanding on how to enter and calculate my data in SPSS.

I have a three way design in which there are 2 variables each in

- Experts vs Novice;
- Guided Discovery vs Control;
- Undisguised vs  Disguised

I've exposed my participants to a pre- and post test but do not understand how to enter the 3rd variable correctly as I've exposed undisguised and disguised together to all my participants.

Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, it seems like you have an AxBxCx(DxS) design. A-C are between subjects. D is pre/post (within subjects). In SPSS you would want a wide data format, where each subject would be a row in your data set.

```
subject expert guided disguised pre post
```

Then you would do a repeated-measures GLM, adding as a factor (call it "test" or whatever) with 2 levels, and name your response (below that, on the same dialog box) "score" or whatever.

On the next screen, select expert guided disguised and add those to "Between-subjects" factors. You should be off to the races then. [This might help](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/one-way-anova-repeated-measures-using-spss-statistics.php) as a guide to the screens.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you have a 2 by 2 by 2 by 2 four-way mixed ANOVA.

- Expertise :Experts vs Novice (between subjects)
- Training: Guided Discovery vs Control (between subjects)
- Disguise: Undisguised vs Disguised (repeated measures)
- Time: Pre versus Post (repeated measures)

In SPSS you can do:
`analyze - GLM - Repeated Measures` then specify your two repeated measures factors. Then put in the between subjects variables as fixed factors and the four "variables" in your spss dataset that represent the four combinations of your two repeated measures variables into the repeated measures section. [Here's an example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/seminars/Repeated_Measures/).